# Fedora 14 boot from CD stalls

Tags: fedora

I'm trying to install Fedora 14 on my Dell T3400 (NVidia).

I created a DVD image and used that to successfully install it on another laptop so I know the image is ok.

However, when I boot from DVD on the desktop, it boots up Fedora and then stalls at the blue screen with the Fedora logo.

Is there a means by which I can diagnose what the issue might be?

Comment: this probably belongs on superuser

Answer (score 0):

If you push esc.. what do you see ??

or try..

Alt+ctrl+f2
Alt+ctrl+f3
 etc

We need to see what the server is actually doing :D

Then its much easier to diagnose

Comment: The boot progress would probably be written verbosely in TTY1 or 7.

Comment: FYI, In Centos - The boot / install process utilizes about 4 TTy's

Answer (score 0):

Type "linux text" at the initial boot prompt, and complete the installation in text mode. Then, once you have a working system, figure out your graphics driver issues.